# how to click this button using Selenium

Tags: r, selenium, selenium-webdriver

on a web page the page number buttons are organized by the following code:

```
<div id="sq-pagination">
  <span class="displaying-num">Displaying 31-60 of 281</span>
  <span>
    <a class="pageing_text_arrow" href="http://www.squawka.com/match-results?pg=1"> « First</a>
    <a class="pageing_text_arrow" href="http://www.squawka.com/match-results?pg=1"> « Prev</a>
    <a class="page-numbers" href="http://www.squawka.com/match-results?pg=1">1</a>
    <span class="page-numbers current">2</span>
    <a class="page-numbers" href="http://www.squawka.com/match-results?pg=3">3</a>
    <a class="page-numbers" href="http://www.squawka.com/match-results?pg=4">4</a>
    <a class="page-numbers" href="http://www.squawka.com/match-results?pg=5">5</a>
    <a class="page-numbers" href="http://www.squawka.com/match-results?pg=6">6</a>
    <a class="page-numbers" href="http://www.squawka.com/match-results?pg=7">7</a>
    <a class="page-numbers" href="http://www.squawka.com/match-results?pg=8">8</a>
    <a class="page-numbers" href="http://www.squawka.com/match-results?pg=9">9</a>
    <a class="page-numbers" href="http://www.squawka.com/match-results?pg=10">10</a>
    <a class="pageing_text_arrow" href="http://www.squawka.com/match-results?pg=3"> Next »</a>
    <a class="pageing_text_arrow" href="http://www.squawka.com/match-results?pg=10"> Last »</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

I would like Selenium to click on the "Next" page (or page 3, that would also be fine). However, I can't figure out how to do this. It does not seem to have an obvious xpath or elementId. How to do this?
(the code comes from this page: http://bit.ly/1lwxxeN, which is the page I am trying to solve this for). I don't mind using javascript code if that would be needed. I am using RSelenium, but other solutions are very welcome as well (so I can try to figure out how to translate the solution to RSelenium).

thanks, Peter

Comment: What code is generated when you record a macro and attempt this click action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if these XPATHs work:

**For 'Next >>' link present under top pagination:**

```
//div[@id='upcoming-fixtures']/center/div[@id='sq-pagination']//a[contains(text(),'Next')]
```

**For 'Next >>' link present under bottom pagination:**

```
//div[@id='upcoming-fixtures']/center/center//div[@id='sq-pagination']//a[contains(text(),'Next')]
```

Answer (score 2):

This xpath selector should work for you:

```
//a[contains(text(),'Next')]
```

So, your code would look like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Next')]")).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

Good `Xpath` by @Richard, anyway for *next page as a number*, you can see, that only the  *currently selected element* is represented as a `<span>` element with specific classname, others are links (`<a>`), so you can query that `<span>` and  take the next link, something like:

```
//span[@class="page-numbers current"]//following::a[1]
```